# Doogee S88 pro Malware + install custom rom

Tags: rom, malware, aosp

I purchased the Doogee s88 Pro a year ago, and it is the perfect phone for my rugged lifestyle, except of the uncertainty of them installing malware / adware in their devices.

I'm trying to install a custom ROM, just normal android with SP Flash Tool, but I can't seem to get it to work. Is anyone able to give steps?

I have the following:,

AOSP,
ADB,
mtk drivers,
SP FLASH TOOL,
SCATTER FILE for device provided by manufacturer.

However whenever I try to direct the "boot" record in SP flash tool, I get a error saying "is this the correct one?" Which then I can't proceed.

Comment: follow the tutorial for custom ROM which is made explicitely for Doogee s88 Pro. first you should unlock bootloader, install [TWRP](https://unofficialtwrp.com/root-twrp-doogee-s88-pro) and disable avb/dm-verity. This is just common [example](https://romprovider.com/havoc-os-doogee-s88-pro) instruction for installing custom ROM

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work via those instructions. Just get boot loop. I think romprovider just have the same type of guide for all sorts of phones to generate clicks as Havoc OS (the ROM) is not officially supporting S88 pro by doogee.

Comment: I have documented everything here: https://github.com/phhusson/treble_experimentations/discussions/2001 Also, in addition to flashing the vbmeta with a blank vbmeta, I also substituted this command with fastboot --disable-verity --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img which also resulted in a bootloop or going straight into fastboot.

Comment: You should have working device first. Enable usb-debugging and authorize. disable avb/dm-verity and get logcat from boot-loop